# Adding an Argument to a Function in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I wish to write an LLVM pass that two arguments of type i32 to select functions.  My first try (sketched below) failed:

```
bool MyFunctionPass::runOnFunction(Function &f) 
{
    Type *int32 = Type::getInt32Ty(f.getParent()->getContext());
    Argument *xC = new Argument(int32, "__xC", &f);
    ...
```

The module verifier crashes if I try the above.  The newly added argument type is junk 0xCDCDCDCD (uninitialized heap memory).  The function type remains:

```
void (i32 addrspace(1)*, i32 addrspace(1)*, i32)
```

instead of being extended by the new `i32`.

Also, adding the parameter directly to the parameter list `Function::getArgumentList()` failed as the `Argument` constructor links itself to the function, and this is detected as a double link.

- *Do I need a ModulePass to do this, or will a FunctionPass suffice?*
- *Is there an elegant way of doing this?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding arguments to a function is surprisingly tricky - as you've discovered, it's not as easy as modifying the argument list.

The most foolproof way of doing it is probably to first create a new function with all the original arguments + the extra arguments, and then call [`CloneFunctionInto`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a152b780fda073380314bbe380fc53376) to embed the original function inside your new function.